# How to print out ascii characters from 0 to 255 in C, displayed in a webpage through Django?

Tags: python, c, django, encoding

I'm working on a C assignment for school. Here's the exact wording of the assignment:

"Write a program that prints a list of the integers 0 through 255 and the corresponding                                        ASCII character. "

The actual code was simple enough:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i <= 256; i++) {
        printf("%d --> %c\n", i, i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, I need to display this output in a webpage with Django. I compiled this code with gcc (with the -std=C99 option enabled), and it outputs fine. However, within the webpage, this does not output anything. Our Django view is using popen2 to open the executable with this code:

```
if os.path.isfile(file_sh):
    output = popen2.popen2(file_sh)[0].read()
```

and the page has been tested to function with all other C code for this class. I've added a print statement within the view to verify that the output of the code is being sent to the browser correctly, and it gets displayed correctly in the terminal but not the browser. In fact, it's not being displayed at all in the browser. Upon further inspection, there is absolutely nothing within the  tag this page would normally display the output of the code. I'm guessing this has something to do with character encoding. Any ideas?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that in my template, I specified the character encoding to be utf-8 with the meta tag.

EDIT 2: A friend of mine has a version that displays the contents of a text file saved on Windows as utf-8 at http://geekingreen.dyndns.org/week02/Assignment-5, but if he tries to display that page with output from an executable, he gets the same problem as me.

Comment: There are no ASCII characters "from 0 to 255". ASCII only defines the values 0 to 126.

Comment: Yes, but aren't there extensions to ASCII that define values past 126? Changing the C code to only print ASCII values to 126 does fix the problems and prints out the output in the browser (starting at 33), but what I'm trying to do is print out those values past 126 as well.

Comment: What does the output look like?

Comment: The output in the terminal or the browser?

Comment: The browser. Are at least *some* of the characters being shown correctly?

Comment: http://i51.tinypic.com/i35u21.png
The output should be in the box below output in the same fassion as the source code is displayed.

Comment: @NathanJones So that's all of it? ie: the box is empty?

Comment: Also are you sure there is output? eg: if you look at the source (not the browser's rendering!), do you see the characters?

Comment: No, I don't, but I can pipe the output of the program to a text file and save it as text file _in Windows_ (not Linux) and it will show the characters.

Comment: There is no such thing as a single well-defined extension to ASCII. The assignment is ludicrous. Consider changing schools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ha, found a way for it to at least render it to the page, the characters don't display correctly but at least it renders something to the page.

The code is simply this:

```
mystring = unicode(mystring, errors='replace')
```

EDIT: Found an even better way

```
import chardet
chartype = chardet.detect(mystring)

# perhaps you may want to check the confidence that it is that encoding first?
# if chartype['confidence'] > 0.5 or something

mystring = mystring.decode(chartype['encoding']).encode('utf-8')
```

Works like a charm, although some characters still seem to be missing it shows more than the previous method.

Comment: It at least shows wild characters on the page, which is better than it was. I'll talk to my professor about it. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

raw bytes with values 128..255 are not valid utf-8 characters, so that is probably your problem.  Specify a Ascii encoding rather than utf-8, as that's what you're doing

Comment: Adding .encode('ascii') to the output still gives me the same behavior.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ:Single bytes with those values are not, although they may be part of a longer UTF-8 sequence.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams http://dev.networkerror.org/utf8/?start=128&end=256&cols=4&search=

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ: Those are characters, not bytes. In UTF-8, they are encoded as 0xC2 0x80 through 0xC2 0xBF and 0xC3 0x80 through 0xC3 0xBF.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ: The reference that you gave is an utter nonsense. Although the heading includes `UTF-8` and it refers to "the UTF-8 code page" (what's that?), the content is absolutely nothing to do with `UTF-8`; it is part of a map from Unicode character numbers (given in "int" (decimal), hex, and (redundantly) as "HTML Entity" (actually a numeric character reference (decimal variety))) to the character rendering, if any.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that character encodings are not the issue.  Although Django uses Unicode strings exclusively and Python uses ASCII strings by default, the UTF-8 character set is backwards-compatible with ASCII.

It's more likely that you are accidentally not including the variable in the page at all.  If your function looks like:

```
def view_function(request):
    output = ''
    if os.path.isfile(file_sh):
        proc = subprocess.Popen(file_sh, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
        output = stdout
    return render_to_response('template.html', {'output': output})
```

and your template looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
    <p>
        {{ output }}
    </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

then you should see the characters on the page.  The text won't break across the same lines as the terminal output, but at least you will see something.  On the other hand, if you change the inclusion tag to {{ ouptut }}, the wrong spelling will cause nothing to be embedded in the page.

Just make sure you don't have autoescaping turned off - if you do, the "-->" string will look like the end of a comment and will break the HTML structure of the page.

One other suggestion: use [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) rather than popen2.  The Python docs mark popen2 as deprecated.

Comment: I know for sure that I'm passing the variable because if I change my C code to only print out ASCII characters up to 127, I see the output just fine in the browser.

Comment: What's your doctype on the page?  If you are using a doctype with an old character encoding, the higher characters may map to some other symbols.  See http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML> is what I'm setting the doctype to.

Answer (score 0):

As others have tried to say, you just need to use the correct encoding.

```
output = popen2.popen2(file_sh)[0].read().decode('cp1252')
```

Comment: As Adam Mihalcin suggested, I rewrote that portion of the view to use subprocess Module instead of popen. The line of code now looks like:
    output = subprocess.Popen(file_sh, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
To try the decode method you appended to that line, I added this below the line above:
    output = output.decode('cp1252')
However, I get the following error:
'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 1058: character maps to <undefined>

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Think of this ÿ (& # 254;), ÿ (& # 255;) or μ (& # 956;). Just remove spaces to get the characters.

You can do pretty easy counting:

```
for i in range(256):
    print '&#%s;<br/>\n' % i
```